# Assert.Pass Xunit NUnit MsTest escape on condition

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, mstest, xunit

I am writing a UI test. This is to check for the error 404 page which I have enabled in Web.Config via;

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirect="~/Errors/"/>
```

This all works fine, however I only have custom errors set to "On" whilst in the "UAT" development environment. If I am in "Dev" or "IST" then I still want to see the default ASP.Net errors.

So now back to the UI test using Selenium

```
    public string GetAlertBoxDetails()
    {
        IWebElement alertBox = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".alert.alert-danger"));
        return alertBox.Text;
    }
```

As you can see I am detecting the Bootstrap ".alert.alert-danger" box and returning the text inside. I then check to see if this text contains "Sorry, that page doesn't exist.". I am using Specflow for the text story.

```
    [Then(@"The user should be told that no such page exists")]
    public void ThenTheUserShouldBeToldThatNoSuchPageExists()
    {
        string alertboxDetail = GetAlertBoxDetails();
        Assert.IsTrue(alertboxDetail.Contains("Sorry, that page doesn't exist."), "Couldn't find the message \"Sorry, that page doesn't exist.\"");
    }
```

This all works fine, **however** I would only like this test to run  in the UAT environment. This is because the element ".alert.alert-danger" will only be found if customErrors is set to "Off". For this I have included this step in the test.

```
    [Given(@"I am in the UAT environment")]
    public void GivenIAmInTheUATEnvironment()
    {
        var env = EnvironmentType;
        if (env != EnvironmentType.Uat)
        {
            Assert.Inconclusive($"Cannot run this test on environment: {env}. " +
                $"This test is only for the UAT environment.");
        }
        else
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
    }
```

Again this works fine. My only problem is that I do not want to use "Assert.Inconclusive" I would rather "Assert.Pass" and say the test passed if it is carried out in a non-UAT environment.

I see XUnit has an Assert.Pass function, but can this be done in MsTest? To force a test to pass WITHOUT continuing to the next Assert. In specflow I am running the "given" step I would like to stop it from continuing to the "Then" step.

Comment: The situation is interesting, but it's not clear exactly what your question is. Please tell us what you are actually asking.

Comment: Hi @Charlie Sorry for not being clear. I have rewritten the question to include more code examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WRT NUnit, you can try Assert.Pass. I can't try it out myself right now as I'm traveling. My uncertainty is that I'm not sure if it will prevent the test from being run if you do it in the SetUp, which is what Given maps to.

My view is that accepting the behavior you looking for, all the code belongs in the test itself and not the Given. What Given would normally do would be to actually create the situation you expect, i.e. change the environment. That's obviously not possible here so I would simply put the environment check in the test itself. I wouldn't even use Assert.Pass unless you want a special message, I'd just skip the test code if the environment is wrong. As a side benefit, this approach works for all three test frameworks.

Although you didn't ask, I have to say that the instructions you have been given to show the test as passing even if it is not run seem pretty crazy to me!

Comment: Hi @Charlie I did exactly that. Removed the UAT check step and then added that check directly into the last two steps.